# Show that a continuous function doesn't exist s.t. for every real $c$, there exist $exactly$ two reals $a, b$ s.t. $f(a)=f(b)=c$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I have a hard time trying to prove this since the only proofs that come to mind are the ones based on a compact domain/closed interval (which is not the case here).

Can someone help me out a bit? Thank you!

Comment: Such functions exist if the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, say (e.g., $f(x)=x-\frac1x$). One more reason to try the Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: You  should not re-post questions  that have already been closed as duplicates.